# Javascript: childNodes.length showing too many elements?

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, nodes

I'm getting some weird results while parsing some XML in JavaScript. I have the following XML in an external file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>

<alerts>
 <alert><![CDATA[ This is the first alert message in a series... ]]></alert>
 <alert><![CDATA[ This is the second alert message in a series, which features a <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="blank">hyperlink</a>... ]]></alert>
 <alert><![CDATA[ This is the third alert message in a series, which features <span class="emphasizedAlertText">text formatted via a css rule</span> ]]></alert>
 <alert><![CDATA[ This is the fourth alert message in a series, which features a <span class="fauxHyperlink" onclick="someFunction();">javascript call</span>... ]]></alert>
</alerts>
```

After grabbing the file via XMLHttpRequest, I have the following function to output it to the page:

```
function testFunc()
{
   var xhrRsp = 'failed to initialize';
   rslt = document.getElementById('rslt');
   if(xhr.readyState == 4)
      {
         if(xhr.status == 200)
         {
            xhrRsp = xhr.responseXML;
            xhrTree = xhrRsp.documentElement.childNodes;
            rslt.innerHTML = xhrRsp + ' (' + xhrTree.length + ' nodes) ';
            for(var i = 0; i < xhrTree.length; i++)
            {
               if(xhrTree[i].nodeName != '#text')
               {
                  rslt.innerHTML = rslt.innerHTML + '<br/>' + xhrTree[i].nodeName + ' (' + xhrTree[i].nodeType + ') ' + ' = ' + xhrTree[i].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
               }
            }
            //rslt.innerHTML = outMsg;
         }
   }
   else
   {
      xhrRsp = 'Loading...';
   }
}
```

When I run the script in the browser, I get this as the result:

```
Click Me
[object Document] (9 nodes) 
alert (1) = This is the first alert message in a series...
alert (1) = This is the second alert message in a series, which features a hyperlink...
alert (1) = This is the third alert message in a series, which features text formatted via a css rule
alert (1) = This is the fourth alert message in a series, which features a javascript call...
```

I'm puzzled as to why the number of nodes comes back as 9, and why every other one of these comes in as #text, which I'm currently filtering out in the above script. I've been looking around and can't figure out what I'm missing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please indent. You'll see, reading the code this sometime usefull ;)

Comment: The script is perfectly fine. `<alerts>` has 9 children, 4 element nodes and 5 text nodes. You are only outputting element nodes. I don't understand your problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the correct behavior for W3C compliant browsers. White space between elements is included in the DOM as a `TextNode`.

You'll probably find that in IE8 and below, the text nodes are not generated. This is because those browsers do not adhere to the specification in this regard.

Comment: Thanks Patrick and Felix. I thought it might be something simple that I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you run that on a crappy browser that doesn't process whitespaces as they should.

Anyway, you are filtering some node with your if, so this is not surprising. Some quick logging could answer your problem very fast . . .